# How do I make all apps use wayland instead of xwayland?

Tags: 20.04, wayland

I enabled Wayland on my Ubuntu 20.04.

It seems that every app needs to be configured individually to use Wayland and not xwayland.

How do I make all apps that support wayland use wayland?

For firefox I had to add `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` in `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` for it to start using wayland instead of xwayland.

Similarly, texstudio, slack, spyder, VScode, joplin, mendeley and essentially every non built-in app does not, whereas I think at least some of them can be configured to launch with wayland manually.

Comment: They do, no additional configuration needed. This seems to be a X-Y problem.

Comment: @ChanganAuto then essentially every app is X-Y

Comment: @Nmath here you go

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make all applications run directly on Wayland. Only applications that are prepared for it can run natively on Wayland. Some apps, like Firefox, appear, for now, to be configured to run on Xorg even if they support Wayland. Therefore, by default, they run on xwayland if you run Wayland, but, as you discovered, that can be changed.

Yes, it depends on the individual application. A big many apps not yet prepared for Wayland will only run on xwayland.

Comment: I understand that not all applications support wayland. I am asking how to configure those that do to run on wayland.

Comment: The answer is in my answer: it depends on the application. You may feel for yourself that the trick with Firefox already seems to be quite specific for Mozilla products.

Comment: If it depends on the application, then I guess the next step is to ask a new question on Ask Ubuntu for each application that you want to do this with.